# Testing for a Successful Redirect with Capybara + RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

Righto, I just want to test that after a user logs in, he is redirected a specific page.

Here's the spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe "the signin process", :type => :feature do

  it "signs me in and redirects" do
    visit ("/")
    within("#login_box") do
      fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'user@gmail.com'
      fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'password'
    end
    click_button 'Sign in'
    #binding.pry
    expect(page.current_path).to have_content 'erb'
  end
end
```

Here's the snippet of code I added to ApplicationController for a devise based redirect:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    session["user_return_to"] || home_preparation_path
  end
end
```

It works fine manually testing in the browser (I am successfully redirected to the home_preparation_path).

Oh, and the view for that path is just the title:

```
#preparation.html.erb

preparation.html.erb
```

The failed test msg I get returns:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(page.current_path).to have_content 'erb'
   expected to find text "erb" in "/users/sign_in"
```

That path is most definitely one defined by Devise. It looks like Capybara isn't automatically going through the motions of redirects, in that it just stops at the Devise controller. What am I missing here to write a proper, passing test?

Comment: Capybara will follow any redirect it encounters. The problem seems to be that the user data you're using for your test (email and password) aren't correct, so on signing failure it redirects to the login page again. Are you creating your user 'user@gmail.com' elsewhere in your code? Also, `current_path` will return the URL as seen by the browser, so I don't understand why you check against 'erb' (the template extension won't be there). I'd rewrite it as `expect(page.current_path).to eq home_preparation_path`

Comment: Thanks so much! I was using a user/pw combo of a real user--not one that I generated ala factory. I also changed my expectation to match the path expected, rather than some text in it. Great suggestion!